# String.Format and log.DebugFormat Currency

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm using log4net to output a formatted message.  The following code

```
log.DebugFormat("Balance: {0:c} ", balance);
```

results in

"Balance: ¤1,000.00"

Why is the odd character appearing and not a $

Comment: Have you checked the region settings on your computer?

Comment: I really think it has to do with log4net, because this works as expected.

log.Debug(String.Format("Balance: {0:C} ", balance));

Comment: what is the culture id of the log4net assembly?  is it culture=neutral?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that it is something to do with your regional settings.

Try something like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(<your culture setting>);
log.DebugFormat("Balance: {0:c} ", balance);
```

If that dosen't work then you can always use the debugger to check the value of:

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;

Specifically check the value of:

```
ansiCurrencySymbol
```

To ensure that it's set to the '$' symbol.

You may also be intersted in this wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29

Which explains what the symbol you are getting is.

Specifically:

```
The currency sign (¤) is a character used to denote a currency, when the symbol for a particular currency is unavailable. 

It is particularly common in place of symbols, such as that of the Colón (₡), which are absent from most character sets and fonts. 

It can be described as a circle the size of a lowercase character with four short radiating arms at 45° (NE), 135° (NW), 225°, (SW) and 315° (SE). It is slightly raised over the baseline.

It is represented in Unicode, as CURRENCY SIGN (U+00A4). In HTML, the character entity reference &curren; or numeric character reference &#164; may be used.
```